# Comparing 2 SSD drives from Samsung

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I'm looking to buy either of the following internal SSD drives from Samsung, for my high-end Windows 10 PC:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07L3D19MY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L3D19MY)

or

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07822Z77M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07822Z77M)

The 2nd one is $45 more expensive. Is it worth the extra cost? Why or why not? Is it faster? Better?

Are SSD drives universal, in terms of fitting in my PC? My box is about 14 months old, high-end specs, so I assume it would fit fine. How can I tell if my PC has room for another internal drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 2nd one is $45 more expensive. Is it worth the extra cost? Why or why not? Is it faster? Better?

Compare the physical parameters of the actual flash storage.

Samsung's "EVO" series uses TLC ([3-level cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell)) flash memory, while their "QVO" series uses QLC (4-layer) flash memory, which is cheaper but *much* slower than TLC and has worse write endurance.

You still see 500 MB/s advertised because both models have a very fast SLC (or MLC?) flash memory cache on top of the main storage, but whenever it fills up (e.g. when you copy a sufficiently large file into the SSD) you get to see the true speed of the underlying storage. (Here's an [example benchmark.](https://youtu.be/WACyyFF_ci0?t=722))

> Are SSD drives universal, in terms of fitting in my PC?

Compare 1) the form factor and the physical connector, 2) the communications protocol.

In your example, both SSDs use the SATA protocol, however, the first one is in 2.5″ form factor and connects through a standard SATA cable (exactly like a 2.5″ HDD) but the second one goes into a M.2 slot on your motherboard.

The first disk will work on mostly all PCs. All 2.5″ SSDs with a SATA connector can work on any computer with a SATA connector.

The second disk should work on all modern PCs, but check first. Many new motherboards have a M.2 slot but they're not always guaranteed to accept all types. M.2 "stick" SSDs have two common types – either SATA or NVMe (both using similar, but differently keyed M.2 connectors). Check your motherboard's manual to find out which protocols it supports on its M.2 slots. You might need to look for "NGFF" (the older name).

Additionally, M.2 SSDs come in different physical dimensions (e.g. "M.2 2280" means 22x80 mm) – any desktop motherboard will accept this very common size, but it's possible that some laptops might only have space for a shorter one.

(As far as I know, there is no difference in performance between M.2 SATA and 2.5″ SATA – they both use the same signalling and they're both equally behind M.2 NVMe. In your case, the difference comes from the flash memory itself.)

Comment: Thank you user1686 for the excellent answer.